# Javascript in custom Form Field Symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, form-fields

I have my form field template as follows:

```
{% block test_question_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div  {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {% set type = type|default('hidden') %}
            <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value }}"/>
            <div class="visible-element"></div>
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

suppose I want my div.visible-element to behave as I define in js file, that is to change value of my hidden input e.g. depending on position on the page.

1. I need to add js file. Where is the best place to do it?
2. Suppose I have like 100 of fields like this. How can I add js only once?

Answer (score 0):

1. The best practice is to add your javascript code in an external .js file
2. With jQuery you can easily repeat the same JS code on all elements :

   $('.visible-element').each(function(){
      // your JS code
   });

Comment: I know. I just need to know where to add that js file.The problem is that I want my Form widget to be independent from base.html.twig file and to add such js file only once.